# Checking to see if a frame exists with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found I can do the following:

```
if($('#notice', parent.frames['header'].document).length>0) { alert("It is here!"); }
```

to check for an item in another frame.
Is there a way to find out of the frame exists?  Specifically I am looking to see if parent.frames['header'].document is there.

Is there a reliable way of doing this?

Update:
Here's my frameset code:

```
<frameset rows="104,*,22" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="header.php" id="header" name="header" scrolling="no" title="Header and Menu" noresize>
    <frame src="main.php" title="Main content" name="main">
    <frame src="footer.php" name="footer" title="Footer" scrolling="NO" noresize>
</frameset>
```

I'm trying to make sure that I can access a div that lives inside of "header".
The downside is that, in some cases, main is replaced with another frameset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know if an element exists, you have to check the length property, see the [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_test_whether_an_element_exists.3F):

```
if ($('#myFrame').length) {
  alert('#myFrame exists');
}
```

In your case I think you want to :

```
if ($('frame[name=header]', parent).length) {
  alert('frame exists');
}
```

Why check the length property?

Because if you pass a selector to jQuery that doesn't match anything, the returned result is a jQuery object, is not a falsy value (null, undefined, 0 or false), in an [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/if...else) the condition is evaluated to bool, and a non 'falsy' value is evaluated always to true:

```
if ($('#nonExisting')) {
  alert('always true');
}

// because 
!!$('#nonExisting') == true;  // and
!!'hello' == true;
!!0 == false;
```

I used `!!` as an example of a simple way of turning any expression into its boolean equivalent, what the if statement does behind the scenes...

**Edit:** Looking at your frameset markup, and assuming that you want to check if the header frame exists from the main page, you can easily do it by :

```
 if (parent.header !== undefined) {
   // frame exists
 }
```

Or simply:

```
 if (parent.header) {
   // frame exists
 }
```

Check this example:

- [Frameset Page](http://jsbin.com/ameqe)
- [Main Page](http://jsbin.com/oqava)

Comment: I tried your second example  
    if ($('frame[name=header]', parent).length) {
and that didn't seem to work for me.  Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the selector:

```
if ($("#myFrame").length) alert("It exists!");
```

Comment: He's doing that for an element within the frame, not the frame itself. Why on earth would you down-vote me because of that? It's completely unrelated.

Comment: They upvoted because my example works. Checking the length of the selector when the selector looks for a frame is a valid option.

Comment: @Josh, I was checking the length of $("#myFrame") for zero. That's for the frame itself. The OP is checking for the length of an element within $("#myFrame"), which is completely different. I edited to provide a more simple example, which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: `$("#myFrame").length;` vs. `$("#notice", $("#myFrame")).length;`

Comment: The first tell you if the frame exists, the second assumes it exists and tells you if the #notice exists. That's the difference.

Comment: With a upvote:downvote ratio like Josh's, he's better suited to troll a blog or forum instead of being an SO snob.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, since you couldn't figure it out yourself, this doesn't even work.  First of all, frames have name attributes, not ID.  So he'd hafta add an ID.  Oh, and $() never returns false.  Never.  But I guess I was crazy and out of line for down-voting.  And yet, my *correct* answer gets down-voted several times.  Great community here!

Comment: This does not seem to work...it always tells me the frame exists even though in some cases it does not.

Comment: Jason, probably best to stick with my first suggestion, and checking .length on the selector. Sorry for changing it up on you ;)